# Javascript calling a function that returns two values but I want only the first (or the second)

Tags: javascript, function-calls

I have a function in javascript that returns two values:

```
function today_date() {
  var t = new Date();
  var day = t.getUTCDay();
  var dayW = t.getDay(); // Day of de week (0-6).      
  return [day, dayW];
}
```

When I call this function (within another function) I whant only one of this values.

```
function print_anything() {
  console.log("Today is the " + today_date() + " of the month.");
}
```

I know it's a very basic and newbie question. But how do I do that?

Comment: Why don't you just have 2 different functions?

Comment: That return statement doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: To be more specific about what canon just said, your function only returns dayW. if you do `return stuff1, stuff2;` both `stuff1` and `stuff2` are evaluated, but only `stuff2` is returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return them in an object literal

```
function today_date() {
  var t = new Date();
  var day = t.getUTCDay();
  var dayW = t.getDay(); // Day of de week (0-6).      
  return { "day" : day, "dayOfWeek" : dayW };
}
```

and access like this

```
function print_anything() {
  console.log("Today is the " + today_date().day + " of the month.");
}
```

or you can return the values in an array:

```
function today_date() {
  var t = new Date();
  var day = t.getUTCDay();
  var dayW = t.getDay(); // Day of de week (0-6).      
  return [ day, dayW ];
}
```

and then access the first one like this

```
function print_anything() {
  console.log("Today is the " + today_date()[0] + " of the month.");
}
```

Comment: It's a lot better to use **"dot notation"**

Answer (score 8):

Does that actually return 2 values?  That's a new one to me.  Anyhow, why not do this?

```
return {'day': day, 'dayW': dayW };
```

and then:

```
console.log("Today is the " + today_date().day + " of the month.");
```

Comment: And it's as simple as that **+1**

Comment: FWIW, the return statement doesn't return 2 values. It's just the comma operator; which returns the last value in the statement. TLDR, only the last statement is returned.